# Is it possible to create a private stellar network without transactions fees?

Tags: fees

I am trying to create a private stellar network that is not geared towards financial transactions.

So transactions fees would not make sense. I would like new block to be created without any fees.

Is it possible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To create a private network without native currency and fees you'd need to modify stellar-core code. But please remember that without fees the network is vulnerable to spam attack.